# Which AI techniques are there that combine multiple models to make sense of data at different stages?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, optical-character-recognition, named-entity-recognition, text-detection

I have been working to design a system that uses multiple machine learning models to make sense of data that is dynamically webscraped. Each AI would handle a specific task, for example:

An AI model would identify text in an image, then attempt to create plain text of what it might be. Once the text is extracted, it would be passed in a stored variable to an AI that can read the text to determine if it is a US city/state.

I tried to look into if others have done this, but didn't find much on it relating to what I was looking for. Does anyone know if there are potential issues with this? Logically, it looks good to me, but I figured I'd ask.

If anyone can put me in the right direction for reading material or further information, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explained a pipeline of AI algorithms for text in images: 1) Text detection, 2) OCR, 3) named entity recognition (NER). There are reams of paper on these topics.

**Extracting City and Country Name from Text**

- [Introducing flashgeotext: extract city and country names from text](https://iwpnd.pw/articles/2020-02/flashgeotext-library)
- [locationtagger -A Python Package for detecting location](https://pypi.org/project/locationtagger/)
- [A Comparison Between Spacy NER & Stanford NER Using All US City Names](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comparison-between-spacy-ner-stanford-ner-using-all-us-city-names-c4b6a547290)
- [CoreNLP NER](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html)
- [Detecting Locations with NER](https://ricedh.github.io/03-ner.html)
- [Papers with code for NER](https://paperswithcode.com/task/named-entity-recognition-ner)
- [Named Entity Recognition: A Practitioner’s Guide to NLP](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/08/named-entity-recognition-practitioners-guide-nlp-4.html)
- [Named Entity Recognition with NLTK and SpaCy](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da)

**Papers on Text from Images**

- [A High-Robust Automatic Reading Algorithm of Pointer Meters Based on Text Detection](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/20/20/5946)
- [Towards Spatio-Temporal Video Scene Text Detection via Temporal Clustering](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.09781)
- [An end-to-end text spotter with text relation networks](https://cybersecurity.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s42400-021-00073-x)
- [Recognizing Text with a CNN](https://ieeexplore-ieee-org.proxy1.ncu.edu/document/8961031?arnumber=8961031)
- [A Framework to Detect Digital Text Using Android Based Smartphone](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9428993)
- [Detected text‐based image retrieval approach for textual images](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1049/iet-ipr.2018.5277)
- [A CNN-Based Approach to Detecting Text from Images of Whiteboards and Handwritten Notes](https://ieeexplore-ieee-org.proxy1.ncu.edu/document/8563217?arnumber=8563217)

**Websites on Text from Images**

- [Deep Learning Based OCR for Text in the Wild](https://nanonets.com/blog/deep-learning-ocr/)
- [Automatically Detect and Recognize Text in Natural Images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html)
- [Tesseract OCR: Text localization and detection](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/25/tesseract-ocr-text-localization-and-detection/)
- [OpenCV Text Detection (EAST text detector)](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/)
- [Detect text in images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)
- [Learning to Read: Computer Vision Methods for Extracting Text from Images](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/learning-to-read-computer-vision-methods-for-extracting-text-from-images-2ffcdae11594)

Comment: I think the keyword for OP is "pipeline". It is common practice to combine detectors, classifiers and other processing to create a pipeline.